# cannot use true (type bool) as type string in function argument

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get Search results from elastic search, but i'm getting this error:

`cannot use true (type bool) as type string in function argument`

Please can anyone can help to resolve it? I'm new to Go programming, so would appreciate suggestions to improve this case in the future.

This my code snippet

```
func SearchCallback(w *http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    api.Domain = "127.0.0.1"

    // search males

    searchQuery := `{
        "query": {
            "term": {"content":"male"}
        }
    }`
    var response2 map[string]interface{}
    response2, err := core.SearchRequest(true, "people", "male", searchQuery, "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("The search of males has failed:", err)
    }
    var values2 []interface{}
    for _, v := range response2.Hits.Hits {
        var value2 map[string]interface{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(v.Source, &value2)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to unmarshal, line 65", err)
        }
        values2 = append(values2, value2)
    }
    fmt.Println(values2)

    jsonV2, err := json.Marshal(values2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed marshalling: line 71", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(jsonV2))
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Go doesn't have implicit type conversion. Since you're new to programming -- what this amounts to is saying that one type cannot be treated as another without explicitly stating that you want it to be treated as such. An int is not a float, a float is not a slice, and a bool is not a string. Sometimes you can use type conversions to fix this, unfortunately, for boolean values you cannot simply use a type conversion. That is, `string(bool)` will not compile.

There are multiple ways to fix this. One is to replace `true` with `fmt.Sprintf("%t",true)`. This is the more general case, if `true` was instead a boolean variable it would return a string that says `"true"` or `"false"` depending. It also generalizes well to other types such as integers, `fmt.Sprintf("%d",myInteger)`, for instance, would convert an `int` to a `string`.

However... in this case since the value is always true, it's needless, just replace `true` with `"true"`. The string that `"%t"` will return will be the string `"true"` so there's no need to go through the conversion hassle.